# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar los items de un Navigation Drawer dependiendo del tipo de usuario (Cliente, entrenador o veterinario) loggeado en Firebase?

Tags: java, android-studio, navigation-drawer, realtime-database

Hice un NavigationDrawer sin utilizar la asistencia que ofrece Android Studio.
Mi proyecto utiliza Firebase Authentication y Firebase RealtimeDataBase.
Al momento de un usuario crear su cuenta, selecciona si es cliente, entrenador o veterinario. Es decir, existen tres tipos de cuenta diferentes.
Después de crear su cuenta e iniciar sesión, se le dirige al usuario al activity principal (NavigationDrawer.java).
Lo que quiero hacer es que dependiendo de cada tipo de cuenta (si es cliente, entrenador o veterinario) se muestren diferentes items.

- Cuando sea cliente, se muestren estos items:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Cuando sea entrenador, se muestren estos items:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Y cuando sea veterinario, se muestren estos items:
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
  Actualmente, para cliente creé: `navigationdrawer_cliente.xml` y sus respectivos items que están en `drawermenu_cliente.xml`
  Para entrenador creé: `navigationdrawer_coach.xml` y sus respectivos items que están en `drawermenu_coach.xml`
  Para veterinario creé: `navigationdrawer_veterinarian.xml` y sus respectivos items que están en `drawermenu_veterinarian.xml`
  Y así está mi código en NavigationDrawer.java (onCreate):

  ```
    String tipoCuenta = "Cliente";
    // Validar qué tipo de cuenta es
    if (tipoCuenta.equals("Cliente")) { // Es cliente
        // Mostrar items del cliente
        setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente);
    } else if (tipoCuenta.equals("Entrenador")) { // Es entrenador
        // Mostrar items del entrenador
        setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_coach);
    } else if(tipoCuenta.equals("Veterinario")) { // Es veterinario
        // Mostrar items del veterinario
        setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_veterinarian);
    }
  ```

Actualmente este código SI me funciona y dependiendo del valor del String tipoCuenta, me muestra los items correspondientes. El problema está al momento de consultar el tipo de cuenta en Firebase RealtimeDatabase. Comparto imágenes de mi BD:

- Ejemplo de un Cliente
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Ejemplo de un Entrenador
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
- Ejemplo de un Veterinario
  [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
  Para realizar la consulta y validar qué tipo de cuenta es, tengo el siguiente código en el método onCreate de `NavigationDrawer.java` (Les recomiendo leer los comentarios que están en cada if para que puedan comprenderlo fácilmente):

  ```
        mDatabase.child("Cliente").child(mAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { // Validar si tipoCuenta == Cliente
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()) { // tipoCuenta == Cliente
                // Mostrar NavigationDrawer_Cliente
                setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente);
            } else {
                mDatabase.child("Entrenador").child(mAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { // Validar si tipoCuenta == Entrenador
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()) { // tipoCuenta == Entrenador
                            // Mostrar NavigationDrawer_coach
                            setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_coach);
                        } else {
                            mDatabase.child("Veterinario").child(mAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { // Validar si tipoCuenta == Veterinario
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    if (snapshot.exists()) { // tipoCuenta == Veterinario
                                        // Mostrar NavigationDrawer_veterinarian
                                        setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_veterinarian);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });
  ```

Lo que hace este código es:
`Paso 1:` Buscar al usuario con su ID en Usuarios > Cliente. Si lo encuentra aquí, ejecuta `setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente);`, es decir, carga los ítems del cliente. Si no encuentra al usuario aquí, va al `Paso 2`
`Paso 2:` Buscar al usuario con su ID en Usuarios > Entrenador. Si lo encuentra aquí, ejecuta `setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_coach);`, es decir, carga los ítems del entrenador. Si no encuentra al usuario aquí, va al `Paso 3`
`Paso 3:` Buscar al usuario con su ID en Usuarios > Veterinario. Si lo encuentra aquí, ejecuta `setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_veterinarian);`, es decir, carga los ítems del veterinario.

El problema no está en la consulta a la BD para ver qué tipo de cuenta es, ya que ya comprobé que si recolecta el valor del campo tipoCuenta. El problema es que no ejecuta las líneas de código `setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente);`, `setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_coach);` y `setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_veterinarian);` cuando lo hago dentro de la consulta a la BD, pero cuando lo hago manualmente (como el primer código que adjunté al principio del if else en donde tengo mi variable `String tipoCuenta = "Cliente"`, si ejecuta estas líneas de código sin problema, o sea, si me carga los items correspondientes.

Comment: Haz debug de lo que te está llegando a este bloque `public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {`, tienes que verificar si la consulta a Firebase está funcionando y qué datos está trayendo. Por otra parte, para usar diferentes menús no es necesario tener diferentes layouts (a no ser que el contenido de los mismos también deba ser distinto). Puedes tener tres menus e inflar el correspondiente según el caso, e incluso un solo menú y ocultar determinadas opciones según el tipo de usuario.

Comment: Ya hice debug y la consulta a Firebase si funciona y si me trae los datos que requiero (o sea, si consulta qué tipo de cuenta es el usuario, ya lo tengo verificado y si funciona la consulta). El detalle es que no ejecuta la línea de código setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente); para llamar al layout correspondiente. Pero por ejemplo, si comento esta línea de código y en su lugar mando un Toast que diga "Si funciona", si ejecuta el Toast correctamente.

Comment: @A.Cedano Me llamó la atención tu comentario de ocultar determinadas opciones (items) de un mismo menú según el tipo de usuario, de esta manera me estaría ahorrando el crear un menú para cada usuario,  ¿Pero cómo podría hacer que se oculten los items?

Comment: En el método `onCreateOptionsMenu` por ejemplo tú puedes decidir qué opciones se muestran o se ocultan según el caso. Sería alcanzar cada item por su id y hacer algo así: `menu.findItem(R.id.item_loQueSea).setVisible(false);` Esto hará que el item llamado `loQueSea` en tu menú no sea visible. Si son muchos items y/o muchos contextos, quizá sea mejor tener un menú ya preparado para cada contexto e inflar el menú correspondiente según cada caso. El layout no debe ser diferente, a no ser que tenga componentes diferentes: textviews diferentes, botones, recyclerview etc.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pues si había usado el `menu.findItem(R.id.item_loQueSea).setVisible(false);` pero me deja los espacios en blanco y no me gustó como se ve, y es por esto que entonces hice el layout y su menú respectivo para cada tipo de usuario, pero pues no puedo inflar el layout que correspondiente dentro de la consulta a Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

El problema principal es que la validación es incorrecta, si el `snapshot` existe nunca va a relizar las validaciones contenidas debajo del `else`:

```
mDatabase.child("Cliente").child(mAuth.getUid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() { // Validar si tipoCuenta == Cliente
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.exists()) { // tipoCuenta == Cliente
          // Mostrar NavigationDrawer_Cliente
          setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente);
      } else {
      ... 
      ...
      ...
```

La validación debería ser como lo señalas al inicio, buscas el tipo de cuenta y en base a esto cargas el respectivo layout:

```
 if (tipoCuenta.equals("Cliente")) { // Es cliente
      // Mostrar items del cliente
      setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente);
  } else if (tipoCuenta.equals("Entrenador")) { // Es entrenador
      // Mostrar items del entrenador
      setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_coach);
  } else if(tipoCuenta.equals("Veterinario")) { // Es veterinario
      // Mostrar items del veterinario
      setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_veterinarian);
  }
```

Comment: No, de hecho la validación si es correcta, la consulta que hago si está bien y ya lo verifiqué.   
Imagínate que en lugar de poner la línea de código setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente); que está dentro del if (spanshot.exist), pongo un Toast que diga "Si funciona", corro la aplicación y si me muestra el Toast. En otras palabras, la validación si es correcta y si entra, el problema es que no me ejecuta el setContentView(R.layout.navigationdrawer_cliente); pero pongo un toast, un sout, o un log y si lo muestra.